# Why images of my HTML appear on my desktop but not on another one

Tags: html, image, display

I have create a lots of HTML for a client.
We are both using Chrome but the images of my HTML are displaying normally but not for my client. 
We clean our cash, I checked 100 times the path, name and extensions of my images and everything seems good to me.

Is there something that can blocked the images on the desktop of my client ?

Thank you very much for your time !

I add an example of my code here :

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="750" class="devicewidth" align="right">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td class="webonly"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="./img/banner-1-FR.png" alt="banner" width="100%" style="display:block;min-width:100%; " class="webonly" /></a></td>
        <td class="mobonly"><a href="#"><img src="./img/banner-2-FR.png" alt="banner-2" width="100%" style="display:none;min-width:100%; " class="mobonly" /></a></td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

My images are all in the file : img

I just can't see where's the problem is.

Comment: Really difficult to suggest anything without looking at your existing code.

Comment: There are some error in console?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, I just add a code containing my images.

Comment: Hi Rafael, I checked the console, I don't see any error. Maybe I should ask to my client if his browser is up to date ? :/

Comment: Did you copy the images also along with the html files. Does the location of image files with respect to the html files same on both machines?

Comment: Hello Vijay, yes I copied all my html and the file "img" (with all the images) into a big one file "email_slicing" and I have sent it to my client. My client just clicked on the HTML to test and informed me that he could'nt see any images..